# Netbeans - Ubuntu - Php - Code suggestion

Tags: php, ubuntu, netbeans, code-completion

I have a strange situation on Netbeans for PHP on Ubuntu. I have enabled code completion and It only happens for me once.

meaning, Ex: if I type `in_array` (php base function) for the very first time it gives me suggestion. Then in the next code line if I type `in_array`, Now I don't see suggestions.

I googled and what I found was to enable code completion.

Does anybody had experience on this strange situation? Any one knows how to make it work?

Comment: No one face this problem before..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what causes this. But I could fix it. Simply uninstall netbeans and re-install it. (re installation done with a fresh download from the site)

Thats it.